# StackLayout работа с динамическим набором TabButton

Tags: qt5, qml

Всем привет.
Вопрос касается StackLayout QML, привожу пример куска кода.

```
 TabBar
{
    id: tabBar

    width: parent.width

    TabButton { id: tabButton1; visible: false; text: qsTr("tabButton1") }
    TabButton { id: tabButton2; visible: false; text: qsTr("tabButton2") }
    TabButton { id: tabButton3; visible: false; text: qsTr("tabButton3") }
    TabButton { id: tabButton4; visible: false; text: qsTr("tabButton4") }
    TabButton { id: tabButton5; visible: false; text: qsTr("tabButton5") }
    TabButton { id: tabButton6; visible: false; text: qsTr("tabButton6") }
}

StackLayout
{
    width: parent.width
    currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
    anchors.top: tabBar.bottom
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

    Button1 { id: button1 }
    Button2 { id: button2 }
    Button3 { id: button3 }
    Button4 { id: button4 }
    Button5 { id: button5 }
    Button6 { id: button6 }
}
```

Так вот, как видите если это запустить то изначально все табы скрыты, но если я по какой то причине сделаю visible = true например для (tabButton1, tabButton4, tabButton6) то я думаю вы понимаете как это будет выглядеть. Буду пустые места на месте других табов, то есть место ими занято но их не видно.
Суть проблема: как можно изменять или показ табов или загрузку их так чтобы нужные мне табы были всегда один за другим?
Была мысль про делегат, но не уверен в этом.
Спасибо за советы.

Comment: Индексы собьются если делать лоадер или делегат.

Comment: тут надо менять ширину или левую margin

Comment: Так какой вариант может быть предпочтительнее? Проблема действительно в том что в однмо случаи может быть 3-4 вкладки, а в другмо штук 8. Но я не совсем понял что вы имеете виду под менять ширину.

Comment: пустые места на месте других табов будут шириной 0

Comment: Думаете это единственный вариант решения такой проблемы?

Comment: или менять концепцию